# Generate pdf from a custom class with cakephp 3

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, cakephp-3.0

I am using the CakePdf plugin for cakephp version 3.2 but I have a doubt according to the documentation and its general usage is like this

```
class Reports extends AppController
{

    public function initialize() {
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->_validViewOptions[] = 'pdfConfig';
    }

    public function test()
    {

        $this->pdfConfig = [
               'margin' => [
                            'top' => 17,
                            'bottom' => 20,
                            'left' => 20,
                            'right'=> 20
                        ],
               'orientantion' => 'portrait',
               'filename' => 'Report.pdf',
               'download' => true
            ];
    }
}
```

The previous example works and it is normal, now I have the need to use the plugin within a class that is not a controller which will be in charge of generating the pdf.

```
use CakePdf\Pdf\CakePdf;

class ReportAnalytical
{

    private $_defaultConfig = [
        'margin' => [
            'top' => 17,
            'bottom' => 20,
            'left' => 20,
            'right'=> 20
        ],
        'filename' => 'Test',
        'orientantion' => 'portrait',
        'download' => true
    ];

    private $cakePdf;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cakePdf = new CakePdf($this->_defaultConfig);
    }

    public function downloadPdfSpanish()
    {

    }
}
```

What is not clear to me is how do I do the same thing I did in the controller but in this class so that its `downloadPdfSpanish` method can be downloaded directly when the pdf is called from the service in the controller, which would be as follows

```
class ReportAnalyticalPdfService
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->reportPdf = new ReportAnalytical();
    }

    public function responsePdfAnalitycalSpanish()
    {
        $this->reportPdf->downloadPdfSpanish();
    }

}
```

call from controller

```
class ReportsGroupsController extends AppController
{

    public function test()
    {
        $response = $this->reportAnalyticalPdf->responsePdfAnalitycalSpanish();
        return $response;
    }

}
```

the architecture that I am applying is ddd with the framework